# the standard way to set content type for a request

Tags: javascript, php

There are two approaches that you can set `content-type` for a request.

### 1: Server Side

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

### 2: Client Side

```
fetch('https://example/api', {
          headers:{                   
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
```

I want to know, is setting the `content-type` the duty of which developer? Backend or frontend? Or both of them? What's the standard way?

Comment: Primarily, this is the responsiblity of the client (front-end developer), so that the server knows which type of content it should act on.

Comment: @31piy So the second approach is right?

Comment: Depending on the country you're working. There are countries where there is a front-end developer and a back-end developer, then there is spain which only have full stack developers :D

Comment: It is entirely implementation-specific. Maybe, server can assume that the content type is JSON, if nothing is specified by the client, in which case, this is server's responsiblity. But in an ideal scenario, you should always specify the content type in the request headers at the front-end side.

Comment: both are doing the same thing, it depends on the situation, if you have header validations on both client and server the both developers need to implement the header

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct and needed when working with two-sided communication. It's just some browsers/programs default their content type, so this is usually not required to implement because client programs send this already.

Sometimes applications only offer read-only resource so providing content-type is not necessary for the client, but is replied from the server side.

Providing the content type is also only required if the resource supports more than 1 content type, which is most often NOT the case.

So the answer, as it is often in software world is: "it depends" :)